# How to avoid using literal strings to narrow disjoint unions in flow

Tags: redux, flowtype

All the examples I find online for narrowing the disjoint union in flowtype uses string literals, like [the official one](https://flowtype.org/docs/disjoint-unions.html#_). I would like to know if there is a way to check against a value from an enum like:

```
const ACTION_A = 'LITERAL_STRING_A';
const ACTION_B = 'LITERAL_STRING_B';

type ActionA = {
  // This is not allowed
  type: ACTION_A,
  // type: 'LITERAL_STRING_A' is allowed
  dataA: ActionAData,
}

type ActionB = {
  // This is not allowed
  type: ACTION_B,
  // type: 'LITERAL_STRING_B' is allowed
  dataB: ActionBData,
}

type Action = ActionA | ActionB;

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  // Want to narrow Action to ActionA or ActionB based on type
  switch (action.type) {
    // case 'LITERAL_STRING_A': -- successfully narrow the type
    case ACTION_A: // doesn't work
      // action.dataA is accessible
      ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately you can't do these because strings are ineligible as type annotations.

If there is any other way around this that doesn't force typing the string literals everywhere I would love to know.

If there isn't a way around this, also accept suggestions on a higher level how to not need to define these disjoint sets for redux actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in my best shape right now, so sorry if I read your question wrong. I'll try to help anyway. Is this what you're looking for?

```
const actionTypes = {
  FOO: 'FOO',
  BAR: 'BAR'
}

type ActionType = $Keys<actionTypes> // one of FOO, BAR

function buzz(actionType: ActionType) {
  switch(actionType) {
    case actionTypes.FOO:
      // blah
  }
```

This should work. Sorry if my syntax is a bit off.

If you're asking how to avoid listing all action types in `type Action = ActionA | ActionB` then sorry, I don't know, I think this is the way you do it. If I recall correctly, a slightly nicer syntax for defining long unions was recently introduce in Flow:

```
type Action =
  | ActionA
  | ActionB
  | ActionC
```

Also, if you don't need individual action types, you can just do

```
type Action =
  | {type: ACTION_A; dataA: ActionAData;}
  | {type: ACTION_B; dataB: ActionBData;}
```

Comment: I was asking about narrowing the Action type to ActionA or ActionB type. That way I would be able to access fields of each subtype without flow complaining. I see that being done with literal strings in the examples, but would like to know if possible with enums

Comment: @xvaldetaro Ah, I see, thanks for updating the question. That's weird. It would seem that refining by constants should work same as refining by string literals. Maybe `type: typeof ACTION_A` in action definition would work?

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to use string literal types for const values:

[Try flow...](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEFUGcFNUgXATgSwHYHNQBtn2ogQy1HgE8AHaSALgCgBjAe1QVAEEBhAFQEkB5AHIB9NtQDkAGR5cAogCU2EoQGUucngIDiIsaAC8oSdPmKVajdrZiA3A2atOvQUIBC4qbIVLV6ra90GRp6mPhb+trRklOz08MjMbPqgAN60oCQU0NQZlIwAZuzc-MJsADRpoAAmBPAEoinIldkIKBgAvuVttJGZMXHMLkmp6VFZOdD5hU7CLuXp1bVuKQsE2WyIhKQAPC1o6AB8HbRdPdFssfGoSef9qIkAPn2XLhF5AK6oF8ygiNCVb-R8AAKBA1MbKWp4UqgAhfVBrOEASmyELBKQqkAA7rh6AALUBA2G3AB0o0R6PS6XoBBgU2KImyqQAkEyiZdiSs2MTGrZKXyYXCOTUCC4hbVrKAQKBoAAPSixP7SjaMRAVFkAI1+BAA1rzKV0+dTaY56Uthvy2cwxXVuZUJVLZfK8JUlYgVRU+ZbUNbRSs9XzNdAdf7QAbQ8cgA)

```
const ACTION_A:'LITERAL_STRING_A' = 'LITERAL_STRING_A';
const ACTION_B:'LITERAL_STRING_B' = 'LITERAL_STRING_B';
```

[image: flow example]